# If show Interstitial ad, onResume() and onPause() not called within Activity

Tags: android, admob, ads

It's quite strange - I didn't guess why my app logic is not executed when pause/resume activity but unfortunately if Ad Mob Interstitial add is on screen these 2 methods are not called at all.

Just tested on Android 4.4, 7.1, 8.1.

Is this behavior expected as normal?

Comment: read https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity

Comment: @sasikumar I'm familiar with activity lifecycle, do I miss something?

Answer (score 2):

`InterstitialAd` is always shown in another activity on top of your app's activity. So, as long as the ad is visible on the screen, your actual activity will stay paused so no lifecycle methods of `yourActivity` will be called and as soon as the ad is closed `onResume` on your activity will be called.